# How to specify device for Metal Compute in CIImageProcessorKernel subclass?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-image, metal-performance-shaders

I've got a custom `CIFilter`, implemented using a subclass of `CIImageProcessorKernel`. The kernel itself is very simple:

```
@implementation ErosionFilterKernel

+ (BOOL)processWithInputs:(NSArray<id<CIImageProcessorInput>> *)inputs
                arguments:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)arguments
                   output:(id<CIImageProcessorOutput>)output
                    error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error
{
    error = error ?: &(NSError * __autoreleasing){ nil };

    id<MTLCommandBuffer> commandBuffer = output.metalCommandBuffer;
    id<MTLTexture> sourceTexture = [inputs.firstObject metalTexture];
    id<MTLTexture> destinationTexture = output.metalTexture;

    NSInteger distance = [arguments[@"erosionDistance"] integerValue] ?: 1;

    MPSImageAreaMin *erodeFilter = [[MPSImageAreaMin alloc] initWithDevice:commandBuffer.device
                                                               kernelWidth:distance
                                                              kernelHeight:distance];
    [erodeFilter encodeToCommandBuffer:commandBuffer sourceTexture:sourceTexture destinationTexture:destinationTexture];
    return YES;
}

@end
```

This works fine, in that it produces the expected result. **The problem** I'm having is that it uses the integrated GPU on a MacBook Pro with two GPUs, and I'd like it to use the discrete GPU. If I pass the result of `MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()` (the discrete GPU) into `-[MPSImageAreaMin initWithDevice:...]`, I get an assertion failure:

> -[MTLDebugComputeCommandEncoder setComputePipelineState:] failed assertion computePipelineState is associated with a different device

This is presumably because the instance of `MTLComputeCommandEncoder` used internally by the machinery responsible for running `-encodeToCommandBuffer:sourceTexture:destinationTexture:` has already been set up to use the integrated GPU. I *think* this comes from the `commandBuffer` pulled from the `CIImageProcessorOutput` object.

**My question**:
Is it possible to specify the GPU to be used by `-encodeToCommandBuffer:sourceTexture:destinationTexture:`? Presumably that involves customizing the output/metal command buffer, but I'm not sure about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which GPU is used should be determined by the `CIContext` that performs the image processing. You should be able to specify the device by using the `[CIContext contextWithMTLDevice:]` initializer.

By the way, since macOS 10.15 there's also a built-in [`CIMorphologyRectangleMinimum`](https://cifilter.io/CIMorphologyRectangleMinimum/) filter that does the same. And there's also a [circular version](https://cifilter.io/CIMorphologyMinimum/) that's available since 10.13.

Comment: Thank you! Specifying the context did indeed do the trick, but I'm more grateful for learning that those two built-ins exist. I wish Apple would keep the Core Image Filter Reference doc up to date... Nice to learn about cifilter.io as well.